# Button to increment value won't show the value?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a very basic JavaScript function that will increment a variable by 1 whenever it is clicked, and the variable will be displayed on the same page and show any updated value. I can't seem to get the variable to write to the HTML document, what am I doing wrong?
I assume the button works fine, but I don't think it is calling the function correctly:

```
function cookieClick(number) {
  cookies = cookies + number;
  document.getElementById("incrementValue").innerHTML = cookies;
```

}

Here's the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6aj2zxb6/

Comment: You weren't using the proper settings on jsFiddle. You needed to load your code in the head of the page https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6aj2zxb6/2/. JsFiddle uses window.onLoad by default

Answer (score 0):

Change the JavaScript setting Load type to No Wrap - in head in jsfiddle

```
This is working fine
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6aj2zxb6/3/

Comment: I already noted that in a comment 10 minutes ago. No need to add it as an answer. Vote to close the question as off-topic due to to a typo instead

Answer (score 0):

You problem was solved by fiddle settings, but if you are interested, try this:

You can assign counter value into cookieClick property

```
function cookieClick(number) {
    if(cookieClick.counter)cookieClick.counter=0;
    cookieClick.counter += number;
    document.getElementById("incrementValue").innerHTML = cookieClick.counter;
}
```

If you have `var counter` in the global (window) scope, it is more easy to overwrite it by another similar code. This is more safe solution. You can use it as a cache in future;-)